# How to dump (and reload) django allauth social apps data to/from file

Tags: python, django

I am using django 2.0.8,Python 3.5 and django-allauth. I have manually created the social app data using the

> Home › Social Accounts › Social applications

menu in the django admin page. However, I want to automate this process (to eliminate manually creating the social apps via the django admin), as I will be deploying the website via Docker, on a virtual machine.

I know `python manage.py dumpdata` allows one to dump data from a django project, but it is not clear how to dump only the data relevant for django-allauth - namely:

- site information (sites app)
- allauth social applications

how do I use `python manage.py dumpdata/load` to dump/load this data?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata):

> Outputs to standard output all data in the database associated with the named application(s).
>
> If no application name is provided, all installed applications will be dumped.

You can pass `allauth` as application name, you can even select which model you want to dump and then load those fixtures using `loaddata`.

Take a look at examples [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures) and [here](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata)